# Android: Launcher Icon width and height in DP

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

In android we could define resources by screen density such as LDPI, HDPI and MDPI.

I am hoping to build a UI that has a TextLayout  that is the same width and height as the the ImageView next to it. The ImageView hosts an image, the same size as the launcher icon (72px for HDPI and so on).

Is there a way to know that the icon has a specific width-height in 'dp' (without kwnoi so I can hard code the XML. I think this is possible because dp is independent of device but couldn't find any way of getting the values in dp.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/holidaylistitem_day"
    android:layout_width="<X>dp"
    android:layout_height="<Y>dp" 
    android:text="1st"/>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/holidaylistitem_type"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

What i need is the X and Y values so both will be of same size.

Comment: Are you the person who has video regarding PHP,Mysql and Apache2 in youtube ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design) has a page that describes recommended [icon dimensions](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).  In short, launcher icons are 48x48 dp.

Comment: I think you are right, it makes sense too, thanks, I will check it out. I didn't read the link in full and missed the detail. Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

there are 4 cases as there are different types of devices in android:

```
ldpi --> 36x36
mdpi --> 48x48
hdpi -->72x72
xhdpi --> 96x96
```

Check this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html).

Comment: Thats the pixel value right? I think @Sparky is right and I have gone through the page briefly but missed the value, which is 48dp.

Pixel values would work, but the problem is, have to write few layout files according to my knowedge. I like to do things in one file, caz I forget to edit the others, onece I do a change to one.

And to your question, about the Youtube vid, ya its me.

Answer (score 1):

As Android Killer says,"there are 4 cases as there are different types of devices in android ...". And you can get dpi.To convert px to dp use this:

> dp = (px*160)/dpi
>   Reference:
>   [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution for your situation, however it is a bit complicated. Here we go:

1. When you cannot decide your icon size, but you are sure it is square, and you want its width/height same as your icon, placed horizontally. You can do this:

   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/holidaylistitem_type"
   android:layout_alignBottom="+id/holidaylistitem_type"
2. Now your TextView position and height is fixed. Then you extend your TextView and do this:

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

   ```
       int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
       int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

       if (width > height) {
           width = height;
       }     
       super.onMeasure(
               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
       );
   }
   ```
3. ImageView sized Square.